# docker-compose with multiple enviroment variables

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

Is it possible to have multiple environment variable files to use with `docker-compose`?

In my folder, I have my `docker-compose`, `.env.prod` and `.env.dev`.

The [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env_file-configuration-option) suggests that you could do it but I'm assuming that example is only for `Dockerfile`s only?

Ideally, I would like it such that I run `docker-compose up dev` for example. Or some variation of that.

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I could see few options -

1. Define two services, one as `dev` and other as `prod` and provide the values i.e `.env.dev` & `.env.prod` as env_file to respective services in the compose file. Post that you can run `docker-compose up -d dev` & `docker-compose up -d prod`.
2. Use a shell hack -
   For dev
   `$ export CURRENT_ENV_FILE=.env.dev`
   For prod
   `$ export CURRENT_ENV_FILE=.env.prod`

   Change compose as below,

   `...`
   `env_file:`
   `- ${CURRENT_ENV_FILE}`
   `...`
3. Use different compose files for different environments.
4. You can feed multiple env files to single service, this isn't suggested but might help you at some point.

   `env_file:`
   `- ./api.env`
   `- ./api2.env`

Comment: Naive question: what does services mean in the context of docker?

Comment: Container definition under services. Such as in - https://github.com/vivekyad4v/kubernetes/blob/master/kubernetes-rolling-deployments/docker-compose.yml - `python` & `nginx` are two different services.

Comment: Ah right I'm with you. So in that example you could do `docker-compose up python` and the `python` service would be the only bit that is ran?

Comment: Exactly, you got it. I prefer `docker-compose up -d python` . Ref - https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/